# Why does my Docker Compose with a MySQL database fail to start?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

Simple hello world docker compose with a mysql database is not working

I'm trying to follow the docker tutorial and docker compose fails. Here's my docker-compose.yml file:

```
services:
  app:
    image: node:18-alpine
    command: sh -c "yarn install && yarn run dev"
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: mysql
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DB: todos

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    volumes:
      - todo-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: todos

volumes:
  todo-mysql-data:
```

The app works if I start the services separately but when I do `docker compose up` the database seems to start but the app service cannot connect to it:

```
> sudo docker compose logs -f
...
app-mysql-1  | 2023-05-24T09:05:29.562329Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.33'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
app-app-1    | Waiting for mysql:3306.......
app-app-1    | Timeout
```

I can connect to the database fine with `sudo docker exec -it <mysql-container-id> mysql -u root -p` and I've tried adding a delay to the app service to make sure it waits for the database but still nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you're not waiting for long enough when you delay the start of your app. This might help: https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/

Comment: Hey Hans, thanks for the quick reply. I did try waiting for 60 seconds and meanwhile (while the app service was waiting) I connected to the database so by the time it continued I knew it was up. In particular I ran a modified app command

`command: >
  sh -c "./wait-for-it.sh -- yarn install && yarn run dev"`

and in my wait-for-it.sh I have:

`!/bin/sh

echo ">>>     before"
sleep 60
echo ">>>     after"`

And I can connect to the database before the logs print "after"

I tried waiting for service_healthy too and I get the same result.

Comment: have you tried to connect the database from your app outside of the container ?
if not, please open the database port in docker compose file and run the app in debug mode and let us know.

Comment: you can have a look at my branch. I have implemented for spring boot app with docker mysql:

https://github.com/Maninder416/spring-boot/tree/spring-boot-mysql-docker-compose-both